# differentiable function with unbounded, integrable derivation

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

(1) Is there an exmaple of function $f\colon [-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable,  with unbounded derivation $f'$ and such that $f'$ is Lebesgue-integrable (i.e. $L^1$-.intebrale)?

I thought about $f(x)=x^2sin(\frac{1}{x^2})$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. This is differentiable, with unbounded derivation $f'(x)=2xsin(\frac{1}{x^2})-\frac{2}{x}cos(\frac{1}{x^2})$ on $[-1,1]$. However, is $f'$ integrable? It think not, because it contains 1/x [Showing that $1/x$ is NOT Lebesgue Integrable on $(0,1]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226114/showing-that-1-x-is-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-0-1)? I extracted this question here [function is not Lebesgue integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3007873/function-is-not-lebesgue-integrable).

Comment: It seems you are looking for a function that has a derivative at every point in [-1,1] and where the derivative is unbounded. That is true for $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x^2)$ since $f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2 \sin(1/h^2)}{h} = 0$.  yet $f'(x)$ is unbounded as $x$ approaches $0$.   Of course the derivative in this case is not Lebesgue (absolutely) integrable as you suggest.  However the answer you accepted shows a function where $f'(x)$ is unbounded near $1$ but $f'(1)$ does not exist.  Are you OK with that?

Comment: Because it is very easy to find an example of a function with an unbounded derivative that is Lebesgue integrable but where the derivative does not exist at one point.  The obvious choice being $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = \sin^{-1} x$ has $f'(x)=(1-x^2)^{-1/2}$ which is unbounded, but $L^1$ (well it's Riemann integrable anyway).

Comment: Does $f'(1) = \lim_{x \to 1-} \frac{\sin^{-1}(1) - \sin^{-1}(x)}{1 - x}$ exist?

Comment: No. It doesn't need to; the function is to be cts on the closed interval and diffble on the open one.

Comment: I know you have that. OP needs to clarify because as worded above a "differentiable" function is sought and only a closed interval is shown.  The OP proposed example is differentiable everwhere in the closed interval.  That is the difficult part, otherwise $\sqrt{x}$, would suffice.