# Lebesgue nonintegrability

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Can you please help me to prove that function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is non-integrable in the sense of the Lebesgue integral on $x \in (0; 1)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226114/showing-that-1-x-is-not-lebesgue-integrable-on-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Riemann integrable functions are also Lebesgue integral with the same integral. Hence the Lebesgue integral $\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\frac 1 xdx=-\log\, \epsilon \to \infty$. Hence the Lebesgue integral is $\infty$.